# AWS Lambda Reserved and Unreserved Concurrency Alarm

Tags: aws-lambda

In our set up, we have lots of AWS Lambda functions, developed by different teams. Some of the them have set a reserved concurrency. This eats out of the total concurrency of the account (1000).

Is there a way to monitor or set an alarm that is triggered when the unreserved currency drops below specific level?

This would be helpful to proactively do something to alleviate the issue and reduce failures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AWS there are pre-defined metrics, related to Lambda concurrency, that are exposed in AWS CloudWatch

**ConcurrentExecutions**: Shows you the concurrent executions that are happening at that moment across the all the Lambda functions in the Account including Reserved and Unreserved.

**UnreservedConcurrentExecutions**: This shows you the total concurrent executions, that are happening at that moment, that are using the Unreserved Concurrency.

The information I was looking for can be seen when we run the CLI command 
    ConcurrentExecutions and UnreservedConcurrentExecutions

```
$ aws lambda get-account-settings

{
    "AccountLimit": {
        "TotalCodeSize": 1231232132,
        "CodeSizeUnzipped": 3242424,
        "CodeSizeZipped": 324343434,
        "**ConcurrentExecutions**": 10000,
        "**UnreservedConcurrentExecutions**": 4000
    },
    "AccountUsage": {
        "TotalCodeSize": 36972950817,
        "FunctionCount": 1310
    }
}
```

It is not possible to get these values in a dashboard. As we cannot execute API calls to fetch and display data in the dashboard.

Solution

We can create a lambda function, and, in that function, we can extract, using the API, the account wide values/settings for ConcurrentExecutions and UnreservedConcurrentExecutions. We can then create new metrics that would send the two values to CloudWatch. We can schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events.
Once we have the metric, we can set the required alarm for the Unreserved Concurrency.

Comment: Neither of these metrics indicates how much unreserved concurrency is left though?